# Visual Composer / WordPress - Edit Multiple Pages of the Same Template at Once

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

When using Visual Composer on WordPress, I am able to set up a template and then use that template for every page I build. HOWEVER, when I want to change something to pages using this template, I have to go back and edit each & every single page.

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a way set up a global Visual Composer template that must abide by the latest configuration? Can it at least be hard coded into an existing PHP template so global changes can be made there?

Answer (score 0):

That was a pain for years. One of the options now is to use WP ACF-VC Bridge plugin (http://wpacfvcbridge.com/). Here are the steps you need to take:

1) Create your page template as VC Snippet (here is a video overview http://wpacfvcbridge.com/vc-snippets/)

2) Set your static content with Visual Composer. You can also dynamically include data from your posts by using ACF Field Picker (here is an overview http://wpacfvcbridge.com/acf-field-picker/).
Note 1: Field context must be custom.
Note 2: these fields must be created with Advanced Custom Fields plugin (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) which is included in WP ACF-VC Bridge. This is enough to cover 99% cases. If you'll need to include other post fields list post title or custom meta field, then you need to look for suitable Visual Composer add-on or write this custom shortcode.

3) Add VC Snippet to your post content with

```
[vc-vc-snippet id="{VC Snippet Template Post ID}"]
```

If you have Visual Composer enabled for your post type (or you can enable it under Visual Composer -> Role Manager) you can use ready VC shortcode to embed VC Snippet.

Now if you'll change your VC Snippet, the changes will be immediately reflected across all posts.